# How to route emails between users in Node.js (MEAN) app?

Tags: node.js, email, express

We have a web app and want to let our users have a conversation with another user via email without knowing the direct email addresses of the other party. Sort of like AirBnb where a host and a guest can reply to each other by sending emails to a unique email address such as v52uh44q0687mbkplx4w0n1rm51j5@reply.airbnb.com

A lot of web apps do this, so we are wondering if there is an easy way (a module or github samples) that we can reuse.

Background info: Our app uses MEAN stack and we use passport to authenticate and node-emailer to send emails out.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For receiving emails there seems to be [mailin.io](http://mailin.io/doc) out there which should work in your node.js environment. You could probably handle the incoming mail in an [express middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) hook and then send in the next middleware the email using nodemailer.

Comment: Thanks Georg. Mailin does look interesting. Will explore it more in coming days.